# How can I Check with adb that there is an external storage Card?

Tags: adb, sd-card

I want to check a file in a sdcard but I have to use ADB.

- I made this :

  adb shell ls $EXTERNAL_STORAGE

It prompts me a list of directories but it's not my sdCard.

How can I find a file in my sdcard using adb ?

Answer (score 0):

@paralleles. You can use the following **adb** command below to check if an external storage card exists:

> adb shell echo /$EXTERNAL_STORAGE

If the above command executes successfully, you'll see a similar output as below :

[image]

Alternatively you can start an **adb shell** session and traverse the directory so as to find the desired file in your sdcard as follows :

> adb shell
>
> cd $EXTERNAL_STORAGE

If the above commands executes successfully, you'll see a similar output as below (depending on the files/folders in your SdCard):
[image]